# With Join And Window Function Getting Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

A Table `Dept`

```
Id   Salary  Dept
1     1000    A
2     2000    B
3     5000    A
4     2500    C
5     3000    D
```

So the Output

```
Id   Salary Dept
 1   6000   A
```

Need To Get the Sum of Salary and Which department as the max salary using Join or Window function

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select d.dept, sum(d.salary)
from dept d
group by d.dept
order by max(d.salary) desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL  you can try this

```
select top 1 d.Dept, Sum(d.Salary) as Salary from Dept d group by d.Dept order by Sum(d.Salary) desc
```